# Broken Windows Server, after crash of VM - CBS_E_SOURCE_MISSING

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-server, windows-server-2016, windows-update, dism

I would like to ask if someone might ever come to a similar problem.

Recently, one of my Hyper-V hosts crashed due to BSOD, and all of the VMs also "went down".

I was able to repair almost every VM but one.

I am performing the DISM.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth command and also sfc /scannow

In CBS logs I can see that there are missing CBS Catalogues:

Checking System Update Readiness.

(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_7083_for_KB5006669~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_7086_for_KB5006669~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_7087_for_KB5006669~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_7089_for_KB5006669~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_7093_for_KB5006669~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_7095_for_KB5006669~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_7098_for_KB5006669~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_7100_for_KB5006669~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_7103_for_KB5006669~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_7104_for_KB5006669~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_7105_for_KB5006669~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_7108_for_KB5006669~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_7112_for_KB5006669~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_7114_for_KB5006669~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_7118_for_KB5006669~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_7122_for_KB5006669~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_7123_for_KB5006669~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_7127_for_KB5006669~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_7128_for_KB5006669~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_7129_for_KB5006669~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_7132_for_KB5006669~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_7137_for_KB5006669~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_7143_for_KB5006669~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_7144_for_KB5006669~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_7146_for_KB5006669~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_7149_for_KB5006669~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_7152_for_KB5006669~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4

The real problem here is that I can not find "KB5006669" on the Microsoft Update Catalogue because it is already EXPIRED...

https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/october-12-2021-kb5006669-os-build-14393-4704-expired-bcc95546-0768-49ae-bec9-240cc59df384

Some details:

Windows Server 2016 Standard
Current build: Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.6796)

On a different VM with a similar problem (also "CBS Catalog Missing") I was able to download the update and use it as a source for DISM repair.

I have tried:

DISM /Online /Cleanup-image /RestoreHealth /source:PATHtoFolderWithExpandedUpdate /LimitAccess

It worked and fixed the missing catalogs.

Unfortunately in the current problem, I am not able to obtain the KB5006669.
Is there any archive site where I can get that update?
I have also tried to use windows server 2016 ISO (the newest) as the source for repair. No luck with that either.